# Meshing four region from four polygon

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I'm trying to generate mesh for axial symetric heat transfer model.
The model contains four regions build from four different kinds of materials.

Inside the steel component is empty air hole present.

I tried to join coordinates from every region, and then use ToBoundaryMesh with LineElement like technique below:

```
el = LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 
     8}, {8, 1}, {2, 7}, {3, 6}}];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coord, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {el}];

Show[bmesh["Wireframe"],
 bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Blue]]]
```

Unfortunately, It seems to be a little bit complicated way, besides I have a problem with an element containing an air hole.

Could you give me any advice how to do that?
What is the best technic to solve this type of task?

I will be appreciated for any help.

Below defined polygons and graphics (pic) in order to you may see what I have tried to meshing.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mcr = Polygon[{{0.275, 0.095}, {0.398, 0.095}, {0.447, 0.308}, {0.447,
      0.323}, {0.415, 0.323}, {0.415, 0.350}, {0.447, 0.350}, {0.447, 
     0.868}, {0.275, 0.868}, {0.275, 0.095}}];
betw = Polygon[{{0.398, 0.095}, {0.447, 0.308}, {0.447, 
     0.323}, {0.415, 0.323}, {0.415, 0.350}, {0.447, 0.350}, {0.447, 
     0.868}, {0.483, 0.868}, {0.483, 0.350}, {0.440, 0.350}, {0.440, 
     0.333}, {0.485, 0.333}, {0.485, 0.308}, {0.423, 0.095}}];
betz = Polygon[{{0.275, 0}, {0.620, 0}, {0.620, 0.772}, {0.528, 
     0.772}, {0.528, 0.588}, {0.513, 0.588}, {0.513, 0.308}, {0.449, 
     0.095}, {0.275, 0.095}}];

st = Polygon[{{0.528, 0.772}, {0.620, 0.772}, {0.620, 0.786}, {0.528, 
     0.786}, {0.528, 0.818}, {0.520, 0.818}, {0.513, 0.818}, {0.513, 
     0.868}, {0.483, 0.868}, {0.483, 0.350}, {0.440, 0.350}, {0.440, 
     0.333}, {0.485, 0.333}, {0.485, 0.308}, {0.423, 0.095}, {0.449, 
     0.095}, {0.513, 0.308}, {0.513, 0.588}, {0.528, 0.588}}];
air = Polygon[{{0.495, 0.608}, {0.513, 0.608}, {0.513, 0.798}, {0.495,
      0.798}}];

steel = RegionDifference[st, air];

pic= Graphics[
  {
   {EdgeForm[Thin], LightBlue, mcr},
   {EdgeForm[Thin], LightGray, betw},
   {EdgeForm[Thin], LightGreen, betz},
   {EdgeForm[Thin], LightYellow, steel}
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.7}, {-0.1, 1}}, Frame -> True
  ]
```

My join cooordinates problem...

```
coord = Join[MeshCoordinates@MeshRegion@mcr, 
  MeshCoordinates@MeshRegion@betw, MeshCoordinates@MeshRegion@betz, 
  MeshCoordinates@MeshRegion@steel]
```

likzew

Comment: In essence you need to clean up your data a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you `betw` data is a bit messed up. I show you how to work around that.

We ignore `betw` and in stead ad a line connecting the `str` and `mcr`

```
boundaries = {mcr, betz, st, air};

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bms = Join[
   ToBoundaryMesh /@ 
    boundaries, {ToBoundaryMesh[
     "Coordinates" -> {{0.447`, 0.868`}, {0.483`, 0.868`}}, 
     "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}}]}]}];
```

Next we use the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) to merge the boundaries.

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
bm = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[Sequence @@ bms];
bm["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Now, we generate the full mesh, with air as the region hole and the other parts set as markers. Because we can we use different refinements in different sub-regions:

```
com = RegionCentroid /@ {mcr, betz, betw, st};
markers = 
  Transpose[{com, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {0.01, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.000025}}];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[bm,
    "RegionMarker" -> markers,
    "RegionHoles" -> RegionCentroid[air]])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Because we have a 0 marker there is still some sub-region not properly connected.

```
groups = mesh["MeshElementMarkerUnion"]
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

We visualize the mesh with colored sub-regions:

```
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[FaceForm[#]] & /@ colors)]]
```

[image]

We see that the red and green area should be connected but are not, you'd need to take a look at that.

Comment: Excellent, It seems you help me very much. I have to review carefully FEMAddOns and Indeed region green and red it is the same material. I will try to correct it. Thank you for your remarks.

Comment: @likzew, the geometry looks like it's an interesting application, would you be willing to contribute that to the [FEMAddOns PDE Model Application collection](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns/tree/master/FEMAddOns/Applications/Documentation/English/Tutorials)?

Comment: of course, if you think so, I will be happy to share the model.